# Best way to sort by date/time in string format?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting, datetime

So I have this list of strings that represent information on a bike-sharing service. In particular, each string represents when a bike was moved by truck to a different station. Each item in the last is represented like so:

```
"By_Truck   ('2019/06/09 15:21:06', 'W 43 St & 6 Ave', '2019/06/09 15:46:49', 'W 33 St & 7 Ave')"
```

What I'd like to do is sort the list in temporal order. However, I'm not sure what the best way to do this is. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Is each entry a `tuple`?

Comment: Please provide the data structure in Python syntax. What is that `ByTruck`? A string? A variable name?

Comment: @trincot its a list of strings. What I have in bold is one string from the list. I'll edit it again to show how it actually is (I just copied from printing it).

Comment: visibly the string contains a tupple representation like `(start-move from-location end-move to-location)` you have to say if you want to sort on the start-move datetime or end-move; Also is date format yyyy/mm/dd or less probable yyyy/dd/mm ? If the beginning of the string is always `By_Truck   (` and you sort on start-move you just have to sort the strings without considering more their content so `sorted(your-list-of-string)` ... difficult to be more simple

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/) package in below manner:

```
import pandas as pd
By_Truck = ('2019/06/09 15:21:06', 'W 43 St & 6 Ave', '2019/06/09 15:46:49', 'W 33 St & 7 Ave')
# Create a DataFrame from the tuple ordered by pairs
df = pd.DataFrame(By_Truck[n:n + 2] for n, i in enumerate(By_Truck) if n % 2 == 0) 
# Set columns names
df.columns = ["date_time", "location"]
# Make type to datetime
df.date_time = pd.to_datetime(df.date_time)
df = df.set_index(["date_time"])
# Sort by index column
df = df.sort_index(axis=0,ascending=True)
```

The result would be:

```
>>> df
                            location
date_time                           
2019-06-09 15:21:06  W 43 St & 6 Ave
2019-06-09 15:46:49  W 33 St & 7 Ave
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems each string has the format

```
"way   ('start-move-datetime', 'from-location', 'end-move-datetime', 'to-location')"
```

If the beginning of the string is always `By_Truck   ("'` followed by the *start-move-datetime* and you sort on *start-move-datetime* you just have to sort the strings without considering more their content so

```
sorted_list = sorted(your_list)
```

or

```
your_list.sort()
```

depending if you want or not to modify your list

If the beginning of the string is not always the same and you still want to sort on *start-move-datetime* you can do

```
sorted(your_list, key=lambda _: _.split("'")[1])
```

If you want to sort on *end-move-datetime* whatever the strings start or not with the same header you can do

```
sorted(your_list, key=lambda _: _.split("'")[-4])
```

In all cases I suppose the date as the format yyyy/mm/dd

```
>>> l = ["By_Truck   ('2019/06/09 15:21:06', 'W 43 St & 6 Ave', '2019/06/09 15:46:49', 'W 33 St & 7 Ave')", 
...      "By_Truck   ('2019/06/08 15:21:06', 'W 43 St & 6 Ave', '2019/06/89 15:46:49', 'W 33 St & 7 Ave')", 
...      "By_Truck   ('2019/06/19 15:21:06', 'W 43 St & 6 Ave', '2019/06/19 15:46:49', 'W 33 St & 7 Ave')"]
>>> 
>>> sorted(l)
["By_Truck   ('2019/06/08 15:21:06', 'W 43 St & 6 Ave', '2019/06/89 15:46:49', 'W 33 St & 7 Ave')", "By_Truck   ('2019/06/09 15:21:06', 'W 43 St & 6 Ave', '2019/06/09 15:46:49', 'W 33 St & 7 Ave')", "By_Truck   ('2019/06/19 15:21:06', 'W 43 St & 6 Ave', '2019/06/19 15:46:49', 'W 33 St & 7 Ave')"]
>>> 
>>> l = ["By_Truck   ('2019/06/09 15:21:06', 'W 43 St & 6 Ave', '2019/06/09 15:46:49', 'W 33 St & 7 Ave')", 
...      "By_Car   ('2019/06/08 15:21:06', 'W 43 St & 6 Ave', '2019/06/08 15:46:49', 'W 33 St & 7 Ave')", 
...      "By_Bicycle   ('2019/06/01 15:21:06', 'W 43 St & 6 Ave', '2019/06/19 15:46:49', 'W 33 St & 7 Ave')"]
>>> 
>>> sorted(l, key=lambda _: _.split("'")[1])
["By_Bicycle   ('2019/06/01 15:21:06', 'W 43 St & 6 Ave', '2019/06/19 15:46:49', 'W 33 St & 7 Ave')", "By_Car   ('2019/06/08 15:21:06', 'W 43 St & 6 Ave', '2019/06/08 15:46:49', 'W 33 St & 7 Ave')", "By_Truck   ('2019/06/09 15:21:06', 'W 43 St & 6 Ave', '2019/06/09 15:46:49', 'W 33 St & 7 Ave')"]
>>> 
>>> sorted(l, key=lambda _: _.split("'")[-4])
["By_Car   ('2019/06/08 15:21:06', 'W 43 St & 6 Ave', '2019/06/08 15:46:49', 'W 33 St & 7 Ave')", "By_Truck   ('2019/06/09 15:21:06', 'W 43 St & 6 Ave', '2019/06/09 15:46:49', 'W 33 St & 7 Ave')", "By_Bicycle   ('2019/06/01 15:21:06', 'W 43 St & 6 Ave', '2019/06/19 15:46:49', 'W 33 St & 7 Ave')"]
>>>
```